# Cherry-pick a merge

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say branch B is a topic branch off of branch A, and you want those changes in branch C.  What does it mean when you cherry-pick the merge commit of branch A and branch B to branch C?

For example, if you use the -m flag to specify the old HEAD of branch A to cherry-pick the merge to branch C, does that simply mean "Take the diff between the cherry-picked commit tree and old HEAD of branch A and apply it to branch C?"

Are there any gotchas for using this method? (e.g. Would branch C look like it's merged to branch A and B?  Would more changes be applied than simply the commits from branch B?)

Comment: Yes `-m1` will take the diff between the first parent (`^1) of the merge commit and the merge result. The gotchya of cherry-picking (or reverting) merges is that git will not *understand* that this has anything to do with a merge or branch B.
To git it will just be a new commit with certain changes. Be prepared for merge conflicts when merging such branches together at a later point of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I usually do this is using [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git rebase --onto C A B
```

This takes the diffs between A and B, and applies those diffs to branch C. As a bonus, the rebase will skip any commits between A and B that perform the same textual change as already exists in branch C.

Update: In the case you mentioned in the comments, remember that Git never overwrites past history. So even after doing the rebase above, you could recreate a new branch head at the commit where B used to be before the rebase. Unfortunately I can't think of a simple way to do that at this time of the morning. Sorry I couldn't be more help, perhaps somebody else will come up with an easy way!

Comment: Sorry, I left out that I wanted the changes in branch B to be applied to both A and C.  The rebase would cause the changes in B to be easily merged with C, but now A is in the situation that C was in.  Anything I can do to have those changes in A as well?

Comment: I'm also sorry that I chose such poor branch names when posing the question :(

Comment: `git rebase` works best with `-i` (= `--interactive`) in my opinion. It let's you see/modify which commits will be rebased.