# How to git pull specific folders?

Tags: git

From `remote`/`ABC` branch I want to pull everything except `P` folder (recursively) to the local current branch.

From `remote`/`XYZ` branch I want to pull only `P` folder (recursively) to the local current branch.

How to do this?

Comment: "*From remote/ABC branch I want to pull everything except P folder…*" Pull everything and remove `P`. "*From remote/XYZ branch I want to pull only P folder…*" If your remote hosting supports `git archive` you can [use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18392680/7976758). Most commercial hostings disable `git archive`; you can try to resort to [`git clone --filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/7976758) (everything found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+one+directory). If nothing helps then alas there is no easy way to fetch just one directory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it easily because git need to know what branch you are on, it sounds like you want to use [Git Submodules](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule) for this, each folder can be a different submodule, this will allow you to have different versions for the folders

However, if this is one time need, you can pull `XYZ` and copy `P` content aside, then pull `ABC` and copy and overridden `P` folder back from the copy you made, the result would be that you are on `ABC` branch but with changes for `P` folder that are the same as in `XYZ`.
note that you will have local changes because you are on `ABC` but your `P` folder is different